# Как выводить рейтинг пользователей в laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, алгоритм, laravel

Всем привет! Нужно на отдельной странице выводить топ 50 пользователей за месяц, за все время. Как в отдельной категории, так и за все категории.
А теперь подробнее.
Сайт еще в стадии разработки, для меня это первый проект на `laravel`. Поэтому прошу помощи у пользователей `Stack Overflow`, не обязательно кодом, можно и просто расписать логику. Я даже представить себе не могу как реализовать эту функцию.
У каждого пользователя(`table users`) есть свои новости(`table news`), которые он ежедневно добавляет. После проверки администрацией каждой новости присваивается в поле status число. Если 1, то пользователю дается рейтинг `+50`. Если 2, то `-30`. Если 3, то не изменяется рейтинг.
Нужно выводить топ пользователей за месяц и за все время, в каждой категории(`table categories`) и во всех категориях вместе.
Как правильно осуществить этот рейтинг? Помогите с логикой рейтинга. А если еще и код подкинете, буду безмерно благодарен.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того чтобы выводить топ по рейтингу, необходимо будет делать запрос вида

```
select sum(u.rate) as rate from users as u
join news as n on u.id = n.user_id
join categories as c on c.id = n.category_id 
group by c.id <-- для учета категорий, для общего рейтинга просто выпилить эту строку
order by u.rate desc
```

Как выше сказали, надо добавить колонку `rate` в таблицу `users`

Answer (score 0):

- Вы пытаетесь одним вопросом решить сложную задачу.
- Для начало, я бы, добавил в таблицу `users` поле рейтинг, и обновлял бы его, а уж вывести топ `10, 50, 100` не будет проблемой.
- Создал бы таблицу с параметрами рейтинга (какое количество баллов
  добавляется за то или иное действие)
- А далее в любых написанных вами методах, увеличивайте или уменьшайте рейтинг.